# How did my inner tube get folded in a Z inside the tire?

Tags: innertube

My rear tire was keep going flat while riding, so I felt around the tire for any punctures or abnormal ‘signs’ that may be causing the problem.
One area felt too thick, and at first, I thought I just overinflated it and somehow the air got trapped. Later, I ended up pushing my bike into the rocks, and when the tire tread came off, I saw that the inner tube had literally folded up into a ‘Z’ shape inside the tire. How did this happen? I have never seen anything like this before.

Comment: Either you had the wrong tube or you were running the tire (almost) flat.

Answer (score 7):

Most likely incorrect tube and tire combo. Check your tube range if it matches the size of your tire. Could also be that you seated the tire incorrectly.

Comment: Like a 29'' tube in a 27.5'' or 26'' tyre.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if your tire is underinflated and you use your rear brake a lot. When you brake, the tire drags and moves a little bit around the rim. Since the tube is anchored at the valve stem, it stretches on one side and bunches up on the other.

Comment: That makes sense. My tire was under inflated, and I usually use my rear brake more than my front one. Thanks.